# Suspension issue in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgraded to Kubuntu 16.04 from Kubuntu 14.04 and I have the following problem: when I try to suspend the computer, I get a black screen and the computer is not suspended. Instead it is still turned on, but it doesn't reply to any command, and the only thing to do is to turn it off by holding the power button. My notebook is a Sony Vaio SVE14A2C5E.
Any ideas to solve this problem??
Thanks in advance.